# Is there a difference in performance between spark read filter and dataframe/sql filter (applied early vs later on)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, lazy-evaluation

Since spark evaluates lazily, please help me understand whether there is a difference in the performance between:

1. a filter applied early on while reading data from file system (eg: AWS S3) using spark.read vs
2. the same filter applied later on using spark sql or dataframe i.e without any filters in the spark.read

Comment: It doesn't matter actually. The spark Catalyst optimizer will figure out the optimizations which can be performed on the code.
https://databricks.com/blog/2015/04/13/deep-dive-into-spark-sqls-catalyst-optimizer.html

Comment: check the execution plan using `df.explain()`